# Rooftop bar in Manhattan?

Tags: usa, new-york-city, nightlife

Currently I'm in New York. I'm looking for a rooftop bar that provides a great overview about Manhattan, but is still affordable. (20 dollar for cocktail at maximum.) Additionally, I want to go there wearing jeans and a t-shirt, so nothing too fancy.

Comment: buy some clothes, my man.

Comment: BTW I didn't realize this Q was so old - sorry :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't recall any **bars** in NYC having a dress code, so T-Shirt and Jeans should be fine as long as you don't come in looking like a complete bum.  Having said that there are quite a few rooftop bars.  Here is the list of some of them that have menus available.

- [230 Fifth](http://www.230-fifth.com/)
- [The Heights](http://www.theheightsnyc.com/)
- [The Local cafe](http://www.dnainfo.com/new-york/20110405/manhattan/top-10-unpretentious-rooftop-bars-manhattan)

But you can simply look at the [top 10 list(?)](http://www.dnainfo.com/new-york/20110405/manhattan/top-10-unpretentious-rooftop-bars-manhattan) to pick the one you fancy the most.

Comment: This is a good overview, so I accpeted the answer. However, I tried to get in 230 Fifth, wearing a Jeans and Tshirt, but was not allowed to get in. Probably because it was Friday night and there were a lot of other trendier people.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Didn't notice this page on the 230 Fifth.  http://www.230-fifth.com/reservations.html.  These guys must think too much of themselves.  Personally I prefer something like: http://www.standardhotels.com/high-line/food-drink/biergarten

Comment: There *are* some bars that have dress codes - those codes are usually something along the line of no jeans, and men must wear collared shirts. But loads of others have "unofficial" dress codes and have bouncers who have sole discretion over whether you're dressed acceptably and attractively enough. A lot of times there isn't any way to know other than to try, though.

Comment: @Laura I don't doubt it but my primary goal visiting a bar is relaxing and dressed up is not relaxing for me. :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally agree that getting dressed up is not necessarily relaxing. Just pointing out that the first statement in your answer is inaccurate - you might not recall bars having dress codes, but there definitely are a lot of them in Manhattan. Whether or not they're worth the trouble is a different question. :)

Answer (score 5):

The [rooftop bar at Hotel Metro](http://nymag.com/listings/bar/hotel_metro_rooftop_bar/) in midtown is unpretentious, cheap (by midtown standards), and gives you a pretty spectacular view of the Empire State building, though not a lot more (since you're more or less surrounded by tall buildings). They have no dress code.

[Top of the Strand](http://www.yelp.com/biz/top-of-the-strand-new-york) (at the Strand Hotel) is similar to Hotel Metro - same neighborhood, same view, same prices.

The [Brass Monkey](http://www.yelp.com/biz/brass-monkey-new-york) in Chelsea is great - laid back, awesome views, very casual, and reasonably priced.

Other than that, my advice is to avoid going to any of the "top-rated" places (unless it's a list of the top 10 "unpretentious" rooftop bars like in Karlson's answer ;), as those will tend to be both pricey and snobby. (FYI: $20 for a cocktail is definitely upscale pricing; mid-range bars will be more like $10-13 for a cocktail and $8-10 for beer.) Using review sites like Yelp will give you a good idea of places convenient for you (NYC is very big!) and will almost always give you a heads-up about unspoken dress codes, rooftops closed for renovations or the off-season, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two hotel bars where you can find quality cocktails (fresh ingredients, top shelf liquor, skilled bar staff):

- Soaked at the Mondrian Soho hotel - they have a great punch program
- Gallow Green is a rooftop bar at the McKittrick Hotel. They have a
  serious classic cocktail program and occasionally the servers will
  take on characters from a bygone era

For a more casual atmosphere, try VU rooftop bar in Korea Town. It's located in a random location, La Quinta Hotel, and offers a spectacular view of the Empire State Building.

Answer (score 2):

[The Jimmy](http://www.jameshotels.com/new-york/eat-drink/jimmy/) at the James Hotel in Soho is a beautiful place to get a drink.

So too is [Le Bain](http://standardhotels.com/high-line/food-drink/le-bain) atop the Standard in the Meatpacking District (probably my favorite rooftop in Manhattan).

But I say skip Manhattan and hop on the L to Williamsburg. [The Wythe](http://wythehotel.com/) Hotel has one of the best rooftop bars in the 5 boroughs.

Anyway, isn't the view of Manhattan better than the view from it?

Answer (score 2):

I realise this question is old but if anyone is looking for something a little unusual with great uninterrupted views of the park and midtown then [the Met have a roof garden/terrace](http://www.metmuseum.org/visit/dining) which is open at certain times of the year (usually the beginning of summer, May/June).

For the cost of admission to the Met (suggested donation) there are reasonably priced drinks for Manhattan with great views out over the park from 5th Avenue.

No dress code required.