# Nice atmosphere in NY at night

Tags: new-york-city, nightlife

I'm traveling to NYC soon. I'm trying to find nice places where to spend the night, but I'm not looking for discos, or music bars really. I'm looking for a place where to stay comfortable, perhaps a Jazz Club or something of that sort.
Is there any other alternative? Something worth seeing at night in NYC?

Comment: http://bigapplejazz.com/harlemclubs.html for the large list of Harlem Jazz Clubs.  What would you consider an alternative?  What kind of things would be worth seeing at night in NYC for you?

Comment: Just in addition:  I am not not much of a fan of Jazz but [Lenox Lounge](http://www.lenoxlounge.com/index.php) was good.

Comment: Even a cafeteria would be okay with me, but a nice one, something different from what you would find anywhere else...

Comment: Anything not too loud and unique?

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9364/rooftop-bar-in-manhattan

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Possibly but these are just bars there are bars with music too which I wasn't looking at. :)

Answer (score 3):

The [NYC.com](http://www.nyc.com/bars_clubs_music) a good starting point to find what you are looking for since there are choices upon choices upon choices of what you can go visit in The City.

Personally I've been to [The Lenox Lounge](http://www.nyc.com/bars_clubs_music/lenox_lounge.52147/editorial_review.aspx), [The BackRoom](http://www.nyc.com/bars_clubs_music/back_room.684175/editorial_review.aspx), which would probably fit your criteria but to list all that might possibly fit your description would take way too long.