# Is there a roof-top bar in the Empire State building?

Tags: bookings, sightseeing, new-york-city, restaurants

My wife and I plan to visit New York for the first time in a couple of days.

A friend of us told us that instead of going to the top of the Empire State building (which implies long waiting times and a rather high price) we should go at a restaurant/bar which is near the top of the tower (but still in the Empire State building) so we can actually get the view, a drink and a longer stay for about the same price.

She can't remember what the name of the place was, just that it was somewhat classy (in the sense: don't go there in shorts).

Would you know what the name of this place is, if you'd recommend it and if we should should book a table in advance ?

Comment: See https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g60763-i5-k6633020-Dinner_at_the_top_of_the_Empire_State_building-New_York_City_New_York.html for possible alternate locations your friend might have been thinking of

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9364/rooftop-bar-in-manhattan?rq=1

Comment: Could your friend have been thinking about the [Rainbow Room](https://rainbowroom.com/) that's 65 floors up Rockefeller Center instead of the Empire State Building? Both buildings have observation decks and maybe the two got confused. It's not cheap—the bar has a $65/person drink minimum to sit outside—(you're paying for the view), and you have to be 21+ and there's a dress code you should be aware of, but you can reserve ahead. Check out their website and decide for yourself.

Comment: Another one was the **amazing, historic bar at the top of the Chrylser Bldg** in the old days. (A bldg in which I worked in the modern era).  I'm not sure if it's been restored lately or ..

Comment: There was the "Windows on the World" and "Wild Blue" restaurants and "The Greatest Bar on Earth" on the top floors of the old World Trade Center. "Windows on the World" in particular was a "men require jackets" kind of place.

Answer (score 9):

I'm almost certain there is **NO bar or restaurant** at the top of the Empire State Bldg.

It's very likely your friend was thinking of one of the other many "famous bars/restaurants at the top of tall buildings."

You just have to suck up the queues, stand in line, and go enjoy the observatory!

Comment: Or pay for the queue jumping ticket.

Answer (score -1):

I used to go all the time. There was a Cipriani bar. I can’t find any info online. I wanted to make a reservation, I guess they closed. But your friend was right, breathtaking, classy and actually less expensive since you seat down and have a drink.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your answer has probably been voted down because it doesn't really answer the question in any definitive way. You give some hints but "I guess it's closed" kind of says, "I don't really know."